# CSS Float border overlap issues

Tags: css, firefox, css-float, border, overlap

I'm trying to float a menu to the left of the page, and when it gets large enough to reach the content below, Firefox bumps the content over exactly as it should... except for the border.

Here is a screenshot with a few items:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o56aZ.png]

And another with several items

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7MGB.png]

"Box 4" gets moved over as expected, but its border stays at the left. O.o

```css
#menu {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

#menu ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#title {
    margin-left: 100px;
    border: 1px #F00 dashed;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 20pt;
}

#title_text {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

#container {
    margin-left: 100px;
}

.topbox {
    width: 30%;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    margin: none;
    border: 1px #F00 solid;
}

.topbox .title {
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px #000 solid;
    padding-top: 1px;
}

.content {
    padding: 2px;
}

#box4 {
    border: 1px #000 solid;
    width: 100%;
}

#box4 .title {
    display: inline;
    border-right: 1px #000 solid;
    border-bottom: 1px #000 solid;
    padding-left: 2px;
    padding-right: 2px;
}

#box4 .content {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC
        "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
        <head>
            <title></title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="title">
                <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" />
                <span id="title_text">Title</span>
            </div>
            <div id="container">
                <div id="box1" class="topbox">
                    <div class="title">Box 1 Title</div>
                    <div class="content">Content goes here</div>
                </div>
                <div id="box2" class="topbox">
                    <div class="title">Box 2 Title</div>
                    <div class="content">Content goes here</div>
                </div>
                <div id="box3" class="topbox">
                    <div class="title">Box 3 Title</div>
                    <div class="content">Content goes here</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="box4">
                <div class="title">Box 4 Title</div>
                <div class="content">Content goes here<br />line break</div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You might want to post this on doctype.com. It's more suited for this style of question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does CSS float not change the width of the following div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475822/why-does-css-float-not-change-the-width-of-the-following-div)

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll not be able to do this with css alone because you're fighting the normal flow. Elements normally are stacked on top of each other and trying to ask one to move out of the way as you go down the page is not how this works.

Answer (score 2):

box4 should have a `clear:both;` property in its css. It should do the trick. I just tested it and it does what you want.

```
#box4 {
    border: 1px #000 solid;
    width: 100%;
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix that by updating your #box4 rule like so:

```
#box4 {
   border: 1px #000 solid;
   margin-left: 100px;
}
```

**Edit** #box4 below a long sidenav css:

```
#box4 {
   border: 1px #000 solid;
   clear: both;
}
```

Comment: If I do that, then when the menu has few items, there will be a useless gap at the left of box4.

Comment: Your other, non-javascript option would be to push #box4 below a long sidenav (edited example)

If you went with Javascript you could alter the style of box4 when the menu is too long so that it went smoothly beside it.

Answer (score 0):

Include the below line above "box4" div.

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

So that your code should look like below :

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div><!-- including this line clear floats --> 
<div id="box4">
 <div class="title">Box 4 Title</div>
 <div class="content">Content goes here<br />line break</div>
</div>
```

Cheers !!!

Comment: That actually pushes box4 below the menu. So I have the three top boxes, and this giant gap under them until the bottom of the menu.

Answer (score 0):

You could float the #box4 to the left..

It would not however have the 100% width ..

As you udnerstand this is not fixable, since the 100% width will always mess something up.. you cannot have it at 100% width but not take up 100% when pushed...

Answer (score 0):

you have missed the **box4** outside of **container**. you can check below snippet.

```css
#menu {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    padding-left: 0px;
}

#menu ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#title {
    margin-left: 100px;
    border: 1px #F00 dashed;
    height: 40px;
    font-size: 20pt;
}

#title_text {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

#container {
    margin-left: 100px;
}

.topbox {
    width: 30%;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    margin: none;
    border: 1px #F00 solid;
}

.topbox .title {
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px #000 solid;
    padding-top: 1px;
}

.content {
    padding: 2px;
}

#box4 {
    border: 1px #000 solid;
    width: 100%;
}

#box4 .title {
    display: block;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: 1px #000 solid;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    text-align:center;
    
}

#box4 .content {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC
        "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
        <head>
            <title></title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                    <li>Item</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="title">
                <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" />
                <span id="title_text">Title</span>
            </div>
            <div id="container">
                <div id="box1" class="topbox">
                    <div class="title">Box 1 Title</div>
                    <div class="content">Content goes here</div>
                </div>
                <div id="box2" class="topbox">
                    <div class="title">Box 2 Title</div>
                    <div class="content">Content goes here</div>
                </div>
                <div id="box3" class="topbox">
                    <div class="title">Box 3 Title</div>
                    <div class="content">Content goes here</div>
                </div>
                <div id="box4">
                <div class="title">Box 4 Title</div>
                <div class="content">Content goes here<br />line break</div>
            </div>
            </div>
            
        </body>
    </html>
```