# div background not showing

Tags: html, css, background

This was going to be the footer for a page.
I have a div with a background colour and 2 paragraphs with the same background colour as the div . One paragraph is floated left the other right. The only place I see the background colour is directly behind the text of the paragraph.

While I did find a work around with tables, I would like to know why it is appearing this way. And why does the div appear to have no background colour when Inspect element says otherwise?

The code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>    
        <style>                                                                                           

            div.holder{
                position:absolute;
                margin-left:auto;
                margin-right:auto;
                width:65%;
            }            

             div.footer{
                position:relative;
                width: 100%;
                background-color: #00A2E8;
            }  

            div.footer p{
                background-color: #00A2E8;
                overflow: hidden
}
           </style>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    </head>
    <body >
    <div class="holder"> 
        <div class="footer" >
            <p style="float:left; ">
                gdfgdfgdfgdffgdf</br>
                dfgdfgdfgd  </br>   
                dgdfgdfg    ,</br>
                dfgdfgdf    </br>
                gdfgdfgf    </br>
                </br>
            </p>

            <p style="float:right;">
                <span>Phone:</span> 555555555</br>
                <span>FAX:</span> 55555555555</br>
                <span>Email:</span>info@example.com</br>
                <span>Website:</span>example.com</br>

        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your last style rule isn't closed

Comment: Did you clear the float?

Comment: JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/4qk7bvmb/1/

Comment: Works if you add ; to overflow: hidden and the missing }.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, on your div. Holder definition add `overflow:auto ` float is a life saver and a huge pain.

Comment: the child elements are floating so they add no height to the parent element. so you need to remove the floats on the child elements or add a height to the parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `position: absolute;` to `div.holder` and If you use that declaration on `div.footer` (instead of `relative` positioning) then `background-color: #00A2E8;` of your `div.footer` will work.

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4qk7bvmb/2/)**

```css
div.holder {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:65%;
}
div.footer {
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #00A2E8;
}
div.footer p {
    background-color: #00A2E8;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This is because it establishes a new block formatting context.

Absolutely positioned elements  i.e. elements where position is `absolute` or `fixed` establishes a new **[block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting)** (in short: BFC)

This is documented in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting):

> Floats, absolutely positioned elements, block containers (such as
>   inline-blocks, table-cells, and table-captions) that are not block
>   boxes, and block boxes with 'overflow' other than 'visible' (except
>   when that value has been propagated to the viewport) establish new
>   block formatting contexts for their contents.

A block formatting context is:

> it is a part of a visual CSS rendering of a
>   Web page. It is the region in which the layout of block boxes occurs
>   and in which floats interact with each other.
>   - [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context)

The spec [states](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting):

> In a block formatting context, each box's left outer edge touches the
>   left edge of the containing block (for right-to-left formatting, right
>   edges touch). This is true even in the presence of floats

Hence the container creating the BFC would contain all the float elements inside it.

Also, **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context)** has clarified this:

> A block formatting context contains everything inside of the element
>   creating it that is not also inside a descendant element that creates
>   a new block formatting context.

---

You should use CSS `clear` property that specifies whether an element can be next to floating elements that precede it or must be moved down (cleared) below them.

When you apply CSS clear property to floating elements, it moves the margin edge of the element below the margin edge of all relevant floats. by [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear)

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4qk7bvmb/3/)**

You can use an extra `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` right before your closing `div.footer` tag.

Comment: This Worked. I don't understand why it worked and would like to know why the position of absolute for the footer made it work while positon relative fails? Also Thank you.

Comment: @MaryMelody Mary please consider updating the answer with what you've learned from that MDN page about "block formatting context". Also Here is the answer to a relevant question on SO that I've posted a few days ago which you might find it helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475822/why-does-css-float-not-change-the-width-of-the-following-div/25476238#25476238

Comment: Thanks! @HashemQolami and I've tried my best and you're a great css genius. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: @MaryMelody Don't mention it. If you are the one who is upvoting my answers please don't; It won't make me a hero :) but will cause the *s[erial upvoting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)*

Comment: @HashemQolami I knew that already and +5 votes won't cause you the serial upvoting and I really like your answers, Seriously! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `.footer` div doesn't contain the `<p>` elements anymore because they are floated. You have to use a `.clearfix`

here a sample:

```
.clearfix:after {
     content: " "; /* Older browser do not support empty content */
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     height: 0;
     clear: both;
}
```

after you add this to your css, your footer should look like this

```
<div class="footer clearfix" >
     <!-- Your paragraphs -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the

```
div.footer p{
    background-color: #00A2E8;
    overflow: hidden
```

You are missing a closing }

change it to:

```
div.footer p{
    background-color: #00A2E8;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

You are also missing a closing p tag in your 'float:right' paragraph tag

Answer (score 0):

The div *does have* a background, it just won't have a size because all of it's children are floated.

Quoting [**MDN float docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float):

> The float CSS property specifies that an element should be taken from the normal flow and placed along the left or right side of its container

meaning that a floated element don't affect it's parent's width or height anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the attribute position for the footer to **fixed**. And it's not necessary to have a background color for the elements as they are contained in the footer block.

```
div.footer{
    margin:0;
    position:fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #00A2E8;
}  

div.footer p {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Hope it works for you :)

Answer (score -1):

remember floating elements add no height to the parent element. remove the floats or add a height. for what your doing you don't need floats you can use positioning absolute left and right. but if you want to use floats add a height to your footer element. see example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>    
    <style>                                                                                           
div.holder{
 position:absolute;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:65%;

}            

 div.footer{
 position:relative;
width: 100%;
background-color: #00A2E8;

}  
div.footer p{
background-color: #00A2E8;
overflow: hidden
height:100px;
       </style>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
</head>
<body >
<div class="holder"> 



<div class="footer" >

<p style="float:left; ">gdfgdfgdfgdffgdf</br>
dfgdfgdfgd  </br>   
dgdfgdfg    ,</br>
dfgdfgdf    </br>
gdfgdfgf    </br>
</br>
</p>

    <p style="float:right;">    <span>Phone:</span> 555555555</br>
            <span>FAX:</span> 55555555555</br>
            <span>Email:</span>info@example.com</br>
    <span>Website:</span>example.com</br>


</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```