# 3 equal and equally distributed columns in css

Tags: css

I want there to be three columns of equal size, and equal gaps in between them. So for right most column there should be no padding or margin at right side and similarly no margin/padding on left of left column. But middle column will have same amount of gap on both sides.

```
html

<div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
</div>

.col {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Consider using one of the many grid-based css frameworks out there (bootstrap, foundation, 960gs, etc.)

Comment: There are dozens of ways to achieve that which may or may not meet you actual needs. What are the circumstances/requirements? *There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.*

Comment: There aren't many uncertainities, Just make simple layout with three columns which have equal space in BETWEEN them and no space outside...if there are lots of ways then just list one.

Comment: @ialarmedalien what i have tried is made three floating columns which align perfectly into three columns but don't have equal spaces in between them. It's simple concept no need for code for that.

Comment: post your html and css with a jsfiddle.net And please don't call it simple concept. If it was you probably wouldn't be here asking.

Comment: i dont want to use some framework just for simple layout problem only.

Comment: If you don't post your code, no one will know what's going wrong and suggest a fix. SO isn't a code writing service; it's for helping with specific coding problems.

Comment: ok i posted code. maybe it will help

Comment: I can think at the moment at least 5 different approaches which may/may not fit your needs.

Comment: Have you googled three column layouts? There are loads and loads of tutorials out there on basic page set ups like this.

Comment: Do you need it responsive? What IE version do you support?

Comment: i don't know what criterias are you looking for to choose between those 'five' approaches as none have been mentioned so far, and you don't understand my needs still despite that i explained it twice already. So just go ahead post one and then we will get somewhere.

Comment: IE10, yes responsive

Comment: i am not saying it's simple to do, im saying it's simple to understand. Some difference

Comment: We get that but this is a place to get help with your code. Not to request code. Big difference

Comment: Yes that is the purpose of stackoverflow, and i thought i had described code good enough in comments. But it wasn't enough, so i've posted it now. Have a look!

Comment: Why don't you search for web page creation tutorials? That way, you can learn about how to create layouts. If you're asking people to write your code, you don't learn anything, and you just end up asking for help again in the future.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Have a look at http://jsbin.com/yimaza/1/edit This is 1 of the 5 I mentoined.

Comment: you can learn from code if it's with some explanation, and if you don't feel like helping then you don't have to. I searched on internet first, but didn't find what i was looking for. I don't know why would you assume that.

Comment: @HashemQolami would it be possible for it to remain responsive but not have margin/gap in between in percentage...so have fixed margin.

Comment: also for future reference would you please also mention other 4 or as many you know. Just describing the technique enough so i can google them would be enough you dont have to write code.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Absolutely, you could change the left/right margins to absolute lengths: http://jsbin.com/yimaza/2/edit

Comment: **#2:** `inline-block` columns, **#3:** CSS Table cells, **#4** [CSS multi-column layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts), **#5** [CSS Flexible box](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/) [layout](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) And **#1** was CSS Float. So please tell me which one would meet your needs? :) If I decide to explain all of them, I should write for an hour.

Comment: no just write float one as answer, i know 5 one tho.

Comment: @HashemQolami i just noticed something that `width:auto` has effect  on middle column. Why? isn't `auto` the default value. So how defining it on element make it expand and take available space. I am sure it has to do with floats

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Long story, but in short the middle div is not floated. It is displayed as a block-level element in normal flow. However giving `overflow: hidden;` to it make it respect the margin boxes of floated elements. Hence it won't overlap the floats. in this case there's no need to specify an explicit `width` so I changed the width to `auto`. More [Explanation Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475822/why-does-css-float-not-change-the-width-of-the-following-div/25476238#25476238).

Comment: Just one more thing, when you use absolute length values on margins, the columns won't have the same width anymore, in order to fix that - at least in my demo - you should use `calc()` expression like so http://jsbin.com/yimaza/5/edit . Other answers are fair enough, thus I'll leave this as a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a grid based css framework (bootstrap, foundation, 960gs, or any other). They really make it a no-brainer to create equal width columns. Following is an example with the version 3 of bootstrap:

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container"><div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">First column</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">Second column</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">Third column</div>
</div></div>
```

---

edit: here's how bootstrap does it. It's really simple and there's actually not much code:

```
* { box-sizing:border-box; }

.container {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.row {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.col-md-4 {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33333333%;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

Important here is the `border-sizing:border-box;` property, which makes sure that padding is added *inside* the specified width. Without it, the default box model value of `content-box` is used, which adds the padding to the width (in effect making the element wider than specified).

Comment: i dont think it's a good design decision to load a framework just to use only the layout part of it.

Comment: Why not? You don't need to load the complete framework. Bootstrap offers a customizer to create a version which contains only the part you need. Other frameworks offer nothing more than a grid/layout system. And maybe you can use more features of the framework, there are many goodies hidden.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer For goodness' sake, man... then just strip out the rules you need and do it.

Comment: i also would like to understand the code for now. I mean could i just rely on other stuff but i'd like to be able to do it myself.

Comment: bootstrap's code is on github, you can look at it and learn from it. They even describe on their website exactly how their grid system is implemented and how you get the correct spacing values.

Comment: you can learn C++ if you looked at C++ long enough too.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer: what's the difference if I put bootstrap's code here, or if you look at the bootstrap source directly?

Comment: no searching in unknown..that's the difference, thanks for the code it's making sense

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous ways of doing this.

### DEMO: http://jsbin.com/qocaxo/1

**CSS**

```
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font: 100%/220% sans-serif; /* demo */
}
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
.col {
    text-align:center;/* demo */
    font-size:200%;/* demo */
    background-color: red;/* demo */
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding:20px;
    margin-bottom:3%;
}

/* the larger viewport css */

@media (min-width:768px) { 
    .col {
        float: left;
        width: 31.33333%;
        height: 300px;
        margin: 0 1%;
    }
    .row {
        margin-left: -1%;
        margin-right: -1%;
    }
    .wrapper {
        overflow-x: hidden
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">1</div>
    <div class="col">2</div>
    <div class="col">3</div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Christina, As a self-taught web developer I have a question: Is this the academical way to have negative margins on `.row` container and hidden `overflow` on the wrapper? Instead of overriding margin of first/last column?

Comment: @HashemQolami : It's no big deal to do this or any number of ways of presenting the content, it's only overflow-hidden on the x at the min-width and it won't interfere or cause issues. Yes this is a lazy way of doing this, you can just remove the first and last. So many slider and so forth hide the overflow, it's not a problem when a fluid layout is involved, for example

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate percentage with this formula

`(your width of element, or padding, or margin) / (total width of container) * 100 = %`

Use this [page](http://resources.sameerast.com/responsive-web-design-formula-easy-calculator.html) for reference.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7whpz625/)

```
.container {
    width: 300px;
    background-color: aqua;
}
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
}
.col {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
}
.col.middle {
    margin: 0 5%;
}


<div class="container clearfix">
    <div class="col"></div>
    <div class="col middle"></div>
    <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```