# How to nurture html blocks in accordance to floated elements

Tags: html, css, pseudo-class

#### Issue#1:

[image: li with float elements]

#### Issue#2:

[image: blockquote with float elements]
The question was asked before, but now with more description and relative code. In my blog I designed the `<ul><li></li></ul>` like:

```
.entry-content ul li{ margin-left: 20px; }
```

and styled `<blockquote></blockquote>` with FontAwesome icon like:

```
blockquote:before{
    content: "";
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    left: -50px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
}
```

The `<li>` issues can be inspected directly at [link#1](http://nishachor.com/unicode-bangla-scripting-with-rishida/) and the `<blockquote>` issue in [link#2](http://nishachor.com/off-track-bandorban-2012-part7/) (at the bottom of the page). In two of the cases the image block is defined with `float:left`.

The problem occurs when a float elements reside nearby, the object goes left or right, but the element can't understand to make its position afterwards, even the `position: relative` was set. You can see how the blockquote resides with a float element on the left.

[image: blockquote with float element]

**How can I sort out the issue with a good visual look?**

Comment: Start with `ul { list-style-position: inside; }` to fix the list items.

Comment: it's a good one for li, right. I can take it. Thanks.

Comment: How do you want the quote mark to look. Should it be positioned underneath the text or should the text be positioned to the right of it like [this example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4m6KG.png)?

Comment: For the second issue you could refer to my answer here: [Why does CSS float not change the width of the following div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475822/why-does-css-float-not-change-the-width-of-the-following-div/25476238#25476238).

Comment: @misterManSam your second option: the text should be position to the right of the blockquote like [your printscr](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4m6KG.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your list items, bring the bullets inside:

```
ul { list-style-position: inside; }
```

[Read more about list-style here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style-position)

To position your quote:

- Remove `position:absolute`, `left` and `top`
- Float it to the left
- Position as desired with margins

```
blockquote:before{
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';
    font-size: 3.125rem;
    color: #ccc;
    content: '\f10d';
    float: left;
    margin-top: -0.4em;
    margin-right: 0.2em;
}
```