# CSS Float not floating?

Tags: css, css-float

I have a snippet with two areas that i want side by side. But the second section refuses to float where it should?

```
<div>
    <div style="width:320px; height: 240px; float:left;">
        <div id="webcam" style="border: 1px dotted #000;"></div>
        <div style="margin:5px;">
            <img src="/img/webcamlogo.png" style="vertical-align:text-top"/>
            <select id="cameraNames" size="1" onchange="changeCamera()" style="width:245px font-size:10px;height:25px;"></select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- This part refuses to float to the right side of the upper content? -->
    <div style="width:320px;height:240px; border: 1px dotted #000;">
        <img id="visitorImage" style="width:320px;height:240px;" alt=""/>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnVisitorImage" runat="server" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the viewport (or container) wide enough to fit both divs? Otherwise the default is to break line...

Comment: `But the second section refuses to float` The second area hasn't been `float`ed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `display: inline-block` to the second div, it worked for me. Display default value for divs is "block" which make them display in a new line; by setting it to "inline-block" you'll force it to work as an inline element (span elements are inline, and they render in the same line as the container element).

Comment: You could probably flesh this answer out a little. At present its more like a comment.

Comment: Thanks @Moob, I edited my answer to do that but apparently didn't work the first time. Thanks anyway for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

add a float property to the styling of the second div. They will float next to each other towards the left.

Generally floating element will ignore other block element, and float to the parent container. Also, its not good practice to write inline styling, try to separate your semantics with your styling.

```
    <div style="width:320px;height:240px;display:block; border: 1px dotted #000; float:left;">
```

Comment: +1 for `Generally floating element will ignore other block element`. For those who are curious, more [explanation here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475822/why-does-css-float-not-change-the-width-of-the-following-div/25476238#25476238)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/o95hzjaf/

```
<div>
        <div style="width:320px; height: 240px; float:left;">
            <div id="webcam" style="border: 1px dotted #000;"></div>

            <div style="margin:5px;">
                <img src="/img/webcamlogo.png" style="vertical-align:text-top">
                <select id="cameraNames" onchange="changeCamera()" size="1"
                style="width:245px font-size:10px;height:25px;">
                    </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- This part refuses to float to the right side of the upper content? -->

        <div style="width:320px;height:240px; border: 1px dotted #000;float:left">
            <img alt="" id="visitorImage" style="width:320px;height:240px;"> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

is this what you want?

Comment: This is poor answering... Please explain your changes instead of just giving the code...

Answer (score 0):

Simply make them both `inline-block`. Add a class (or inline css) to get these elements to display side by side without the need for floats and [clearfixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix):

```
.inlineblock {display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;}
```

EG:

```
<div>

<div style="width:320px; height:240px;" class="inlineblock">
    <div id="webcam" style="border: 1px dotted #000;"></div>
    <div style="margin:5px;">
        <img src="/img/webcamlogo.png" style="vertical-align:text-top"/>
        <select id="cameraNames" size="1" onchange="changeCamera()" style="width:245px font-size:10px;height:25px;">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>    
<!-- This part now sits on the right side of the upper content (space permitting) -->
<div style="width:320px; height:240px; border:1px dotted #000;" class="inlineblock">
<img id="visitorImage" style="width:320px;height:240px;" alt=""/>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnVisitorImage" runat="server" />
</div>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pbb6d9ww/