# Flowing one floated Div around another Div of set height

Tags: html, css, alignment

Say I have two divs, one floated left and one float right, and the right floated div has a set height.
I want the contents inside the left floated div to fill out the space below the right floated div if the height increases to that point.

I'm not sure if this is even the right approach, so let me know if there is a better way. A few searches left me to the possibility of using tables(?) but I'm unsure about that.

```css
.A {
  float:left; 
  height: 50%; 
}
.B {
  float:right;
  height:200px; 
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class = "A">
  Content of Unknown Height Will Go here
</div>
<div class = "B">
  Contact Information Box
</div>
```

So far, I have just the two divs floating side by side and the left div's contents extend much further down.

[image: here is what I am going for]

Comment: Post your HTML and CSS please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't float the left element, and place it after the right-floated one:

```css
#left {
  height: 200px;
  background: #B5E61D;
  border: 5px solid;
}
#right {
  float: right;
  background: #FF7F27;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 5px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="right">Right floated div</div>
<div id="left">Left non-floated div</div>
```

Comment: For those who are curious about the reason, explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475822/why-does-css-float-not-change-the-width-of-the-following-div/25476238#25476238