# Layout of HTML div tags with float property

Tags: html, css, css-float, stylesheet

I have one question:

- Why the output of the following HTML code is like this?

[image]

Here is the code:

```html
<div style="width: 500px; float: left; border-style: solid; padding-left: 10px;">This box occupies 516 pixels on the browser window</div>
<div style="width: 400px; float: left; border-style: solid; padding-left: 10px; margin-left: 50px;">This box occupies 466 pixels of the browser window</div>
<div style="width: 966px; border-style: solid; padding-left: 10px;">This box occupies 982 pixels of the browser window</div>
```

I am expecting that the third div should appear under the other two floating divs but it looks like it is containing them?

Did I use the float property in a wrong way?

P.S. I am using Mozilla Firefox as a browser.

Thank you

Comment: OK, I think that I have to use the clear:left property in the third div? but why I have this weird box when I don't use the clear:left?

Comment: Thanks Hashem, can you explain to me why I have such an output when I don't use the clear:left?

Comment: This is just the expected behavior of CSS float which [I've explained it fully here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25475822/why-does-css-float-not-change-the-width-of-the-following-div/25476238#25476238). In fact, line boxes respect to the floated element so they will wrap it, the box itself will ignore the floated element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Block elements are laid out “behind” floated elements, only their inline content floats around the floated elements.

If you want it “under” them, then `clear` the float.

Answer (score 1):

Logic : You will have to use float: left; for 3 DIV also.

Answer (score 0):

**Define**

```
clear:both;
```

your **third div** `clear:both;`

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/m76bqvs6/)**

**[Why Clear both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871710/why-clear-both-css)**

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by clearing the float property after the second div, which should result in the third div positioning under the first and second div. Like so:

```css
CSS
.clear{
clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 500px; float: left; border-style: solid; padding-left: 10px;">This box occupies 516 pixels on the browser window</div>
<div style="width: 400px; float: left; border-style: solid; padding-left: 10px; margin-left: 50px;">This box occupies 466 pixels of the browser window</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div style="width: 966px; border-style: solid; padding-left: 10px;">This box occupies 982 pixels of the browser window</div>
```